# alert is working but no other code in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I have an image.html file in dreamweaver.

in source code I link an js file called img.js

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>PHOTO</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/img.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

if an use an alert in img.js

```
alert("My First Jquery Test");
```

it shows correctly in web page but if write some javascript code like

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("p2").style.color="blue";
</script>
```

The paragraph above was changed by a script.

nothing shows..why and how I show this?

Comment: Your `<head>` starts, then ends with `</body>` ?!

Comment: why u r using External js file for only one alert statement ?

Answer (score 0):

The script is working as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dqDKX/).
Report your fully HTML file if still have problem.

Remember:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

      <script>
         document.getElementById("p2").style.color="blue";
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replicate the problem on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Do it right

edit img.js

```
window.onload=function(){
    alert("My First Jquery Test");
   document.getElementById("p2").style.color="blue";
}
```